# Check network connection for Domain Connectivity

Tags: .net, outlook, add-in

I am working on a COM add-in project for Outlook 2010 in .Net. This add-in program automatically files guests emails on the SQL server database in the background. As per requirements, I have to check database server connection before every email is being sent out or received and automatically file if connected otherwise mark as offline email. If any point of time user connects to the DB server an email synchronization process should perform.

To check the DB connection I am using Ping command to DB server, it works if a user logged on the domain but outside the domain it takes a lot of time to respond, occasionally it returns false although user connected.

I was working on the line to check network connection first and then check database connection but if a user connected to internet but not to DB server ping command fails and slows down the application. What I am looking is to check if a user connected to the domain then check the DB connection only. To perform this check on every email I need a very fast method.

I tried `Dns.GetHostByName()` and `System.Net.WebRequest()` before doing ping but they are very slow to respond if user not on the domain, resetting the `System.Net.WebRequest()` Timeout setting makes no difference.

I appreciate if someone can advice me on this.

Thanks in advance